# pandas merge and update efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Iam getting df1 from the database.
Df2 needs to be merged with df1. Df1 contains additional columns not present in df2. df2 contains indexes that are already present in df1 and which rows need to be updated. the dataframe are multi indexed.

What i want:
-keep rows in df1 that are not in df2
-update df1's values with df2's values for matching indexes
-in the updated rows keep the values of the columns that are not present in df2.
-append rows that are in df2 but not in df1

My Solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data={'idx1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'idx2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'one': ['df1', 'df1', 'df1', 'df1', 'df1'],
          'two': ["y", "x", "y", "x", "y"]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'idx1': ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], 'idx2': [4, 5, 6, 7], 'one': ['df2', 'df2', 'df2', 'df2']})

desired_result = pd.DataFrame(data={'idx1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], 'idx2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                            'one': ['df1','df1','df1','df2', 'df2', 'df2', 'df2'], 'two': ["y", "x", "y", "x", "y",np.nan,np.nan]})



updated = pd.merge(df1[['idx1', 'idx2']], df2, on=['idx1', 'idx2'], how='right')
keep = df1[~df1.isin(df2)].dropna()
my_res = pd.concat([updated, keep])
my_res.drop(columns='two', inplace=True)

my_res = pd.merge(my_res,df1[['idx1','idx2','two']], on=['idx1','idx2'])
```

This is very inefficient as i:

1. merge by right outer join df2 into index only columns of df1
2. find indexes that are in df2 but not in df1
3. concat the two dataframes
4. drop the columns that were not included in df2
5. merge on index to append those columns that i've previously dropped

Is there maybe a more efficient easier way to do this? I just cannot wrap my head around this.

EDIT:
By mutliindexed i mean that to identify a row i need to look at 4 different columns combined.
And unfortunately my solution does not work properly.

Comment: I just ran your code, and it looks like your desired output is slightly different from the result you get, namely that instead of the two `NaN` values you have `x` and `y`. Also, you say "the dataframe are multi indexed." but that doesn't appear to be true.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html), [`Dataframe.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and [`Series.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html):

First we append df1 and df2. Then we drop the duplicates based on column `idx1` and `idx2`. Finally we update the `two` column `NaN` based on existing values in df1.

```
df3 = (df1.append(df2, sort=False)
          .drop_duplicates(subset=['idx1', 'idx2'], keep='last')
          .reset_index(drop=True))

df3['two'].update(df1['two'])
```

```
  idx1  idx2  one  two
0    A     1  df1    y
1    B     2  df1    x
2    C     3  df1    y
3    D     4  df2    x
4    E     5  df2    y
5    F     6  df2  NaN
6    G     7  df2  NaN
```

Comment: thank you so much this is perfect, and so much shorter!

Answer (score 3):

[Merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the dataframes, [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html) the column `one` with the values from `one_`, then drop this temporary column.

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['idx1', 'idx2'], how='outer', suffixes=['', '_'])
df['one'].update(df['one_'])
>>> df.drop(columns=['one_'])
  idx1  idx2  one  two
0    A     1  df1    y
1    B     2  df1    x
2    C     3  df1    y
3    D     4  df2    x
4    E     5  df2    y
5    F     6  df2  NaN
6    G     7  df2  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

One line `combine_first`

```
Yourdf=df2.set_index(['idx1','idx2']).combine_first(df1.set_index(['idx1','idx2'])).reset_index()
Yourdf
Out[216]: 
  idx1  idx2  one  two
0    A     1  df1    y
1    B     2  df1    x
2    C     3  df1    y
3    D     4  df2    x
4    E     5  df2    y
5    F     6  df2  NaN
6    G     7  df2  NaN
```